# How can i solve : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I've created a JFrame on eclipse for authetification by a username and a password which i recover them through mysql workbench database, and i have imported the library "jar" of mysql connector java and build it on the project.
the code is the one given bellow:

```
pnlBtnlogin.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                String pseudo = txtUsername.getText();
                String mdp= pwd.getText();
        
                try {
                    
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection conn =(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/utilisateurs","root","Mrayhana123");
                    Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
                    String sql="select * from etudiant where username='"+pseudo+"' and pwd='"+mdp+"'";
                    ResultSet result = stm.executeQuery(sql);
                    if(result.next()) {
                        lblLoginMessage.setText("vous êtes connecté");
                        lblLoginMessage.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    else {
                        lblLoginMessage.setText("Pseudo ou mot de passe incorrect !");
                        lblLoginMessage.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    }
                    
                } catch(Exception e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();               
                    }
```

**And the result : **

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
> jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/utilisateurs   at
> java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
> at
> java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
> at ProjetSra.FrameLogin$4.mouseClicked(FrameLogin.java:161)     at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6638)
> at
> java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)  at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)   at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at
> java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at
> java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

Thank you for helpin me.

Comment: You're missing a `:` after `jdbc:mysql`

Comment: @BenjaminM yes that's true thank you so much , i have been searching all the day about this problem